# prepositions "on" and "about" a subject. Any difference at all? Or there is a slight difference between them

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

I am explaining my question with an example. From what I learnt, a book about spy is a book, probably a novel, in which one or numerous spies take major roles in the storytelling. Tom Clancy's books of the adventures of Jack Ryan are books about spy. A book on spy in one of Clancy's book could be a Ryan's training manual when the CIA had trained him. However, [this source said no difference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/a-book-on-about-something.1751072/). [Another said the preposition "about" connects general information with the object and "on" connects specific and detailed](https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/168250-It-s-a-book-on-or-about-It-s-a-question-on-or-about).

Comment: on a topic, about a subject. a book on **spies** or **on a spy**. about a spy and about spies, too.

Answer (score 1):

*A book about spy* isn't idiomatic English. We would say *about a spy, about spies, about spying/espionage*, or books such as Tom Clancy's would be described as *spy novels, spy fiction* etc.

When referring to a non-fiction book, you can us both *about* and *on*, but *on* probably does have a stronger implication of a serious work of reference or textbook.

Comment: Thank you. From what you typed, A book on a subject is formal language and a book about a subject is in common use, I think. Common language is not idiomatic English. So the difference is actually not about the choice of preposition but formal or casual use of the English language.

Comment: I _didn't_ say that 'a book on a subject' was more formal language, I said that it usually implied a more serious, specialist kind of book. (There are reference books on English law with titles like 'Chitty on Contracts', 'Clerk and Lindsell on Torts'.) A book 'about' a topic could be a popular non-fiction work. This isn't a hard-and-fast rule - as I said, you can use both.

Comment: Right, like a book on butterflies, for instance. You can use both the on is more sciency.